# Real number * Integer = Integer

Tags: real-numbers

Lets say $r$ is a real number and $I_1, I_2$ are integers. I want this, $$r*I_1=I_2$$ This is not possible all the time so, I allow to add an epsilon $\epsilon$ to the real number such that $$(r+\epsilon)*I_1 = I_2$$ What is the smallest value of $\vert\epsilon\vert$ ? For example: $r = 0.31, I_1 = 30 \therefore \epsilon = -0.01, I_2 = 9$
 I can solve the problem numerically. That is, I consider only two decimal precision and search for the smallest $\epsilon$. 
 
 As in the example, I round lets say $r=0.3111$ to $r=0.31$ and multiply it by $I_1$ if the result is an integer I stop or $r := r \pm 0.01$ then do the previous steps.

$ I_1 \in \{24, 25, 30, 48, 50, 60\}$ and $r$ is given. We are seeking for smallest $\vert\epsilon\vert$ and $I_2$ is the output. Any $I_2 \ge 0$ is acceptable.

Comment: If you allow bigger and bigger $I$, then you need smaller and smaller $\epsilon$. For instance, if $I_1 = 10$, then for any $r$ we get $|\epsilon|\leq 0.05$, while if $I_1 = 100$, then $|\epsilon|\leq 0.005$. You need to have a limit like $|I_1|\leq n$ or something before we can say anything about $\epsilon$.

Comment: If you have $(r+\varepsilon)I_1=I_2$ then you have $sI_1=I_2$ where $s=r+\varepsilon$ is a real number.

Comment: @Arthur I updated the question as you suggest.

Comment: You can throw away $24,25$ and $30$, since if a given $\epsilon$ works with any of those, it's going to work with $48,50$ or $60$ as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume for now that both $r$ and $I_1$ are given.

Consider the real value $r*I_1$. Let $I_2=[r*I_1]$ be the nearest integer, i.e. the integer you get when rounding $r*I_1$.
Then $\epsilon=I_2/I_1 - r$ is the smallest change that makes $(r+\epsilon)*I_1$ an integer.

You have several choices for the value of $I_1$, so simply calculate $\epsilon = [r*I_1]/I_1 - r$ in each of those cases and choose the best one.

Comment: Thank you ! Perfectly works.

Answer (score 1):

The value of $|\epsilon|$ can be arbitrarily small if you pick $r$ correctly, given the integers $I_1,I_2$. The choice of $r=\frac{I_2}{I_1}-\epsilon$ for any arbitrarily small $\epsilon$ says that $|\epsilon|$ can be as small as we like.

Comment: we can not choose r. It is given us like, r = 0.31. And for I1, It will be one of these values {24 - 25 - 30 - 48 - 50 - 60 }. To put it simply, let me give an example. (0.31+e)*24 What is the smallest value of e to make this expression an integer ?

Comment: So the values you're given are $r$ and $I_1$, and _not_ $I_2$?

Comment: exactly, I'll update the question as discussed. Thank you.

Comment: All the examples for $r$ are rational -- are they allowed to be irrational?

Comment: Yes, any real number for $r$ is ok.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for bounds on the size of $\epsilon$ then, not just the smallest value.

Answer (score 0):

One way to reduce the trial and error is to find the [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) for $r$.  Terminating the continued fraction expression gets you good rational approximations to $r$, which you can check and see if the error is small enough or the denominator is in the range you want.